# GROUP BY brings duplicates and it`s not grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, common-table-expression

I'm trying to `GROUP BY` every Authority id in a row by date and Off/OnStreet. I don't understand what is going wrong in the SQL query. It brings me duplicates or repetitive AuthorityId instead of grouping everything by authority ID base on date and On/Offstreet.

[image]

And this is my SQL query

```
WITH ParkeonCTE
AS
(
SELECT 
    OccDate = CONVERT(DATE, LocalStartTime),
    TotalOccSessions = COUNT(SessionId),
    AuthorityId,
    (CASE
        WHEN OC.OspId IS NULL THEN 'OffStreet' ELSE 'OnStreet'
        END
    ) AS ParkingContextType
FROM Analytics.OccupancySessions AS OC
WHERE AuthorityId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  CONVERT(DATE,LocalStartTime), AuthorityId, OspId
)

  SELECT CONVERT(DATE,OC.OccDate),
   OC.TotalOccSessions,
   OC.ParkingContextType,
    OC.AuthorityId
  FROM ParkeonCTE AS OC
  GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, OC.OccDate), OC.AuthorityId, OC.TotalOccSessions, OC.ParkingContextType
  ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE,OC.OccDate) DESC
```

Comment: I see no duplicates in that image, `TotalOccSessions` has a different value on every row. What duplicates are you talking about? Also, why a `GROUP BY` with no aggregation in your `SELECT`?

Comment: There are no duplicate rows. The query works as it should. Explain what you want to do.

Comment: I wanted to say that, if you check the AuthorityId, all of them which are ending with E.G f4 for a specific date and a specific parking context should be counted in 1 line..and then for off street as well. And then we should do the same for another AuthorityId

Comment: Also, there's no need to `CONVERT` `OC.OccDate` to a `date`, it's already one, as defined in your CTE `ParkeonCTE`.

Comment: All I want is: 2018/01/01 / 100 Sessions for instance / OnStreet / 21323-sdfs32432-34543sd which is authority ID. 
And then, the same for OffStreet and that`s it...Hopefully it makes sense

Comment: And what about TotalOccSessions?

Comment: I was missing an aggregation ( SUM  of TotalOccSessions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer query is grouping on 1 too many.

```
...
SELECT 
 CONVERT(DATE,OC.OccDate) AS OccDate,
 SUM(OC.TotalOccSessions) AS TotalOccSessions,
 OC.ParkingContextType,
 OC.AuthorityId
FROM ParkeonCTE AS OC
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, OC.OccDate), OC.AuthorityId, OC.ParkingContextType
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, OC.OccDate) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Aggregate function `SUM()`

```
WITH ParkeonCTE
AS
(
SELECT 
    OccDate = CONVERT(DATE, LocalStartTime),
    TotalOccSessions = COUNT(SessionId),
    AuthorityId,
    (CASE
        WHEN OC.OspId IS NULL THEN 'OffStreet' ELSE 'OnStreet'
        END
    ) AS ParkingContextType
FROM Analytics.OccupancySessions AS OC
WHERE AuthorityId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  CONVERT(DATE,LocalStartTime), AuthorityId, OspId
)

   SELECT 
      CONVERT(DATE,OC.OccDate),
      SUM(OC.TotalOccSessions),
      OC.ParkingContextType,
      OC.AuthorityId
  FROM ParkeonCTE AS OC
  GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, OC.OccDate), OC.AuthorityId, OC.ParkingContextType
  ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE,OC.OccDate) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks - Got it now :)